# play framework 2: test a request with a json string as body

Tags: scala, testing, playframework-2.0, specs2

I have the following action

```
def save() = Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>
  request.body.asOpt[IdeaType].map { ideatype =>
    ideatype.save.fold(
      errors => JsonBadRequest(errors),
      ideatype => Ok(toJson(ideatype))
    )
  }.getOrElse     (JsonBadRequest("Invalid type of idea entity"))
}
```

And I'd like to test it

The web service works ok with curl like this:

```
curl -X post "http://localhost:9000/api/types" 
--data "{\"name\": \"new name\", \"description\": \"new description\"}" 
--header "Content-type: application/json"
```

which correctly returns the new resource

```
{"url":"/api/types/9","id":9,"name":"new name","description":"new description"}
```

I'm trying to test it with

```
"add a new ideaType, using route POST /api/types" in {
  running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())) {

    val json = """{"name": "new name", "description": "new description"}"""

    val Some(result) = routeAndCall(
      FakeRequest(
        POST, 
        "/api/types",
        FakeHeaders(Map("Content-Type" -> Seq("application/json"))), 
        json
      )
    )

    status(result) must equalTo(OK)
    contentType(result) must beSome("application/json")
    val Some(ideaType) = parse(contentAsString(result)).asOpt[IdeaType]

    ideaType.name mustEqual "new name"

  }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
[error] ! add a new ideaType, using route POST /api/types
[error]     ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to play.api.libs.json.JsValue (IdeaTypes.bak.scala:35)
[error] controllers.IdeaTypes$$anonfun$save$1.apply(IdeaTypes.bak.scala:36)
[error] controllers.IdeaTypes$$anonfun$save$1.apply(IdeaTypes.bak.scala:35)
[error] play.api.mvc.Action$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:170)
```

I followed the advices on this question: [Play 2 - Scala FakeRequest withJsonBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910405/play-2-scala-fakerequest-withjsonbody)

Am I missing something?

--

Kim Stebel solution worked fine, but then I tried with withJsonBody, like this:

```
    val jsonString = """{"name": "new name", "description": "new description"}"""
    val json: JsValue = parse(jsonString)

    val Some(result) = routeAndCall(
      FakeRequest(POST, "/api/types").
      withJsonBody(json)
    )
```

and I get the following error:

```
[error] ! add a new ideaType, using route POST /api/types
[error]     ClassCastException: play.api.mvc.AnyContentAsJson cannot be cast to play.api.libs.json.JsValue (IdeaTypes.bak.scala:35)
[error] controllers.IdeaTypes$$anonfun$save$1.apply(IdeaTypes.bak.scala:36)
[error] controllers.IdeaTypes$$anonfun$save$1.apply(IdeaTypes.bak.scala:35)
```

any idea?

Comment: on which line does the excepton occur?

Comment: the exception occurs on the "def save() = Action..." line...

Comment: paste your routeAndCall may help.

Comment: my routeCall is there...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably need to pass in a `JsValue` as the body of the request. Change the line

```
val json = """{"name": "new name", "description": "new description"}"""
```

to

```
val jsonString = """{"name": "new name", "description": "new description"}"""
val json = Json.parse(jsonString)
```

Comment: You are right, kim. But I thought that the FakeRequest should parse it. When I use it from curl, I'm just sending a string...

Comment: But in that case it gets parsed by the framework before the request object is created.

Comment: Sounds pretty logical. Now I'm trying with withJsonBody, to have a less verbose code, but it doesn't work... (I edited the question...)

Comment: James Roper describes this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/GU2qeQ9naaA/eKwL-xz-oRsJ), saying that a controller using `parse.json` will require you to send a `Request[JsValue]`.  However, I couldn't get it to work until I created a request using `FakeRequest(POST, "/mypath").withHeaders("Content-type" -> "application/json").withBody[JsValue](json)`, where json is a `JsObject`.