# Test REST API Controller in scala and play framework 2.1

Tags: scala, rest, playframework-2.1

Play Framework v 2.1 with scala, I am trying to test my ProductController with invalid call (missing parameters), I am suppose to get BadRequest response..

Controller code is return *Ok*(Json.toJson(some class..)) or *BadRequest*(Json.toJson(some class..)) incase something went wrong.

I Defined the test class:

```
class ProductApplicationTests extends PlaySpecification
with Mockito 
with ProductServiceComponent
{
  lazy val productService = mock[ProductService]
  ... other things 

def app = FakeApplication(
withoutPlugins = Seq("com.typesafe.plugin.RedisPlugin"),
withGlobal = Some(
  new GlobalSettings {
    override def getControllerInstance[A](clazz: Class[A]) = clazz match {
      case c if c.isAssignableFrom(classOf[ProductController]) => new ProductController(ProductApplicationTests.this).asInstanceOf[A]
      case _ => super.getControllerInstance(clazz)
    }
  }
)
)

def mockStuff = {
productService.addProduct(any[AddProductRequest]) returns
    DTOResponse(product.id.get)

productService.updateProduct(any[UpdateProductRequest]) returns
    DTOResponse(product.id.get)

productService.deleteProduct(any[DeleteProductRequest]) returns
    DTOResponse(product.id.get)  
}
step(mockStuff)

"Application" should {
"Get product with no tenant Id" in {running(FakeApplication()) {
 val req = FakeRequest(method = "POST", uri = routes.ProductController.getProducts("en_US", "1", "1").url,
              headers = FakeHeaders(
                Seq("Content-type"->Seq("application/json"))
              ),
              body =  None
            )
    val Some(result) = route(req)

    status(result) must equalTo(400)
```

**Problem**:
I get error:

```
Cannot write an instance of None.type to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[None.type]
```

I have followed this post: [Play 2 - Scala FakeRequest withJsonBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910405/play-2-scala-fakerequest-withjsonbody) And i dont understand what im doing wrong..
When i send this code as test it works..

```
"Get product with valid parameters" in new WithApplication(app) {
  val result = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/v1.0/products?lang=en_US&t=1&ids=1,2"))
  result must beSome
   status(result.get) must equalTo(OK)
  contentType(result.get) must beSome.which(_ == "application/json")
  contentAsString(result.get) must contain("products")
  contentAsString(result.get) must contain("notFoundIds")
}
```

Thanks for any comment/answers..

By the way my global.scala looks like:

```
override def onBadRequest(request: RequestHeader, error: String) = {
 var errorResponse:ErrorResponse[String] = ErrorResponse(ErrorCode.GeneralError, "Error processing request", 500)
 errorResponse.addMessage(error)
 Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.toJson(errorResponse)))
}

override def onError(request: RequestHeader, ex: Throwable) = 
{
  var errorResponse:ErrorResponse[String] = ErrorResponse(ErrorCode.GeneralError, "Error processing request", 500)
  errorResponse.addMessage(ex.getMessage)
  Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.toJson(errorResponse)))
}
```

And if i run Get in RestAPI test client i get:

```
{"code":100,"message":"Error processing request - Missing parameter: t"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [source for FakeRequest](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Fakes.scala?source=c), you'll notice that you need to set the body to `AnyContentAsEmpty`.  On a sidenote, should that first test method be a POST?  Your other examples seem to be GETs.

As for your second issue with running Get in RestAPI tet client, the error message seems pretty clear, you need to provide the parameter t as you did in the previous example `val result = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/v1.0/products?lang=en_US&t=1&ids=1,2"))`